# React native google sign in failed - error code 16 (CANCELED)

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

I am working on google-sign-in but getting an error CANCELED and error code is 16.

**Steps to Reproduce**
I can able to check status for GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices(); and popup open to select account. When choose account it show the error CANCELED code 16.

**Expected Behavior**
It should return user info.

**Actual Behavior**
it give error CANCELED code 16.

**Environment:**
***1. android/build.gradle:***

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}
```

***2. android/app/build.gradle:***

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pacelogin"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
 }
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
       }
      }
     }

 dependencies {
  implementation (project(':react-native-google-signin')){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
 implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
 implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1"
}
```

> Update : I have refereed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin#signin) link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Namrata you first check whether you are generating correct keystore file for your project.
1 . Make sure you give correct password and alias name which you passed to create keystore file. 
2. store the keystore file in your(/android/app/) path or you can create folder named keystore and then pase it there.(/android/app/keystore/)

> make sure you are specify in which mode you are working. If it is debug mode then use debug section or else use release mode.

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../app/YOUR_FILE_NAME.keystore")
            storePassword "YOUR_STORE_PASSWORD"
            keyAlias "YOUR_ALIAS_NAME"
            keyPassword "YOUR_PASSWORD"
        }
       /* release {
            storeFile file("../app/debug.keystore")
            storePassword "YOUR_STORE_PASSWORD"
            keyAlias "YOUR_ALIAS_NAME"
            keyPassword "YOUR_PASSWORD"
        }*/
    }
```

3. Verify the dependencies you are using are correct.